# zoom in phonegap for android

Tags: android, cordova

How do I enable zoom on my phonegap app for android users?

I tried to customize "Sample/src/com/phonegap/Sample/Sample.java" but it still just doesn't work:

Any ideas?

```
package com.phonegap.Sample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.phonegap.*;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;

public class Sample extends DroidGap
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

        WebSettings ws = super.appView.getSettings();
        ws.setSupportZoom(true);
        ws.setBuiltInZoomControls(true); 

    }
}
```

Comment: Your code actually worked perfectly for me. Thanks!

Comment: This too worked for me

Comment: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
For Cordova 5, see this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/33207352/1290746
------------------------------------------------------------------------

Answer (score 2):

This has worked for me, the above solution didn't.

```
package com.my.app;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.ZoomDensity;

import com.phonegap.*;

public class MyDroidActivity extends DroidGap {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
        WebSettings settings = appView.getSettings();
        settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        settings.setSupportZoom(false);
        settings.setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.FAR);
    }
}
```

This is where I found it, the credit goes to them!
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-android/issues/120

Comment: it works for me......but when i am redirecting from index.html to index2.html zooming doesn's work for me in index2.html ......

Answer (score 1):

```
<meta name="viewport"  content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=0.8, user-scalable=1" />
```

That worked for me ;).

It should be placed in the meta section of your html pages

Answer (score 0):

Erks answer didn't worked for me (thought I wanted only to scale, no pinch zooming).

But this worked: [How to change PhoneGap's screen size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8661064/how-to-change-phonegaps-screen-size)

---

EDIT: It was long time ago since I played with this, so I will just copy-paste answer (just in case if for some reason stackoverflow decides to remove that link as stated in comment).

> I found a way to do that. I already had tried by using a meta
>   viewport, but I guess I don't put everything that is necessary.
>
> Just put this meta tag below and everything should be fine.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />
```