# Enabling viewport pinch-zoom in Phonegap Android application has no effect

Tags: android, cordova

I need to be able to turn pinch-zoom on and off using the viewport setting on my Android PhoneGap app.

But I'm unable to get viewport to affect pinch-zooming at all when using PhoneGap. **I cannot turn on Pinch-zoom in PhoneGap, but when browsing with the Android Native browser to the webpage everything works fine.**

I have spent a lot of time searching for a solution, without any result.

I created a very simple index.html for testing, having viewport setting like:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes" />
```

As some has suggested I have also tried the viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=1" />
```

Other solutions for Android PhoneGap would be to enable Android Native Pinch-Zoom which have been suggested here:
[zoom in phonegap for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668344/zoom-in-phonegap-for-android)
But this will not work for me, since I need to be able to control the pinch-zoom from javascript. I.e. I need to be able to use javascript to change the viewport setting, to control when pinch-zoom is available (user-scalable=yes / user-scalable=no)

Please observe that other viewport settings like "initial-scale" and "target-densitydpi" seems to work fine. For example setting initial-scale=2 starts the app zoomed.

(I'm currently testing pinch-zoom on PhoneGap 1.4.1 and HTC Desire HD Android 2.3.3)

I'm beginning to think I have missed something obvious, since I find so little information about similar problems...

The minimal index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Minimal AppLaud App</title>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.4.1.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        var onDeviceReady = function() {
            document.getElementById("devready").innerHTML = "OnDeviceReady fired.";
        };

        function init() {
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
        }   
      </script>  

  </head>
  <body onload="init();" id="stage" class="theme">
    <h2>Minimal AppLaud App</h2>
    <p> LOTS OF TEXT WHICH HAVE BEEN REMOVED HERE </p>

    <p><span id="devready">onDeviceReady not fired.</span></p>

  </body>
</html>
```

Appreciate any ideas that you might have!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pinch Zoom in Android with Phonegap and jQUERY Mobile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006684/pinch-zoom-in-android-with-phonegap-and-jquery-mobile)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have exactly the same issue and besides testing different viewport settings, I have tried the suggestions from this: [Pinch Zoom in Android with Phonegap and jQUERY Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006684/pinch-zoom-in-android-with-phonegap-and-jquery-mobile) but I can't make it work (testing on Samsung Galaxy SII, Android 4.0.3). However, others have reported successful pinch-zooming using the tips from the link. Hope it helps you too!

Answer (score 13):

Are you using PhoneGap Build? It is not possible with PhoneGap Build.

With Desktop PhoneGap, if you haven't already, follow the PhoneGap [Getting Started with Android Guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android) and set your code up in an Eclipse Project.

Once set up, edit your Main Java file, as in the getting started guide: 
Add the following imports:

```
import android.webkit.WebSettings; 
import android.webkit.WebSettings.ZoomDensity;
```

Below the 'super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");' line that you put in, as part of the start up guide, add:

```
settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
settings.setSupportZoom(true);
settings.setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.MEDIUM);
```

Clean and build your project - zooming should now be allowed.

To restrict how far users can zoom in, add a meta tag, like the one below to every HTML page:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.5, user-scalable=1">
```

Comment: In my case I had to use this: super.appView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
super.appView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.MEDIUM);
super.appView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);

Comment: If you get a build error when doing this, try @jopin's answer below instead.

Answer (score 6):

Just confirmed Pinch Zoom as working on the following Android Phones:

- Samsung Galaxy S820L Android 4.4
- LG Sunset L33L Android 5.0

With PhoneGap CLI (not the service), on Windows:

```
C:\>phonegap --version
5.4.1
```

Android SDK Tools Verion:

```
24.4.1 (from the SDK Manager)
```

Here is the code for MainActivity.java (platforms\android\src\com\phonegap\helloworld):

```
package com.phonegap.helloworld;

import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;

public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        loadUrl(launchUrl);

        WebView webView = (WebView) appView.getEngine().getView();
        WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();

        settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        settings.setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.MEDIUM);
        settings.setSupportZoom(true);
    }
}
```

And this is in index.html:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=3, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

One additional note - with this call:

```
settings.setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.MEDIUM);
```

got this when building:

```
uses or overrides a deprecated API - Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details
```

Commented it out, and Zoom was not affected.

Thank you guys!!!

Comment: Thanks this was very helpful!

Comment: Amazing!! Thank you so much!! Works great for my Kindle Fire 7 (7th gen) app which has meta tags to make some pages zoomable and some not.

Answer (score 2):

Whoever even after this didn't find a solution, I found an answer in Github:

https://github.com/LouisT/cordova-useragent/issues/1

Basically you have to:

```
import android.webkit.WebView;
```

And then:

```
// super.appView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
// super.appView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.MEDIUM); 
// super.appView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
// Instead use this
WebView webView = (WebView) appView.getEngine().getView();
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
settings.setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.MEDIUM);
settings.setSupportZoom(true);
```

Comment: I'll be linking to this answer from some other threads as so many referred to the webview object without showing how it should be initialized.

Answer (score 1):

For cordova 5.x.x you need to use the solution from https://github.com/LouisT/cordova-useragent/issues/1

```
import android.webkit.WebView;

WebView webView = (WebView) appView.getEngine().getView();
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
settings.setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.MEDIUM);
settings.setSupportZoom(true);
```

For me, it was required to change ZoomDensity.MEDIUM to WebSettings.ZoomDensity.MEDIUM

Answer (score -5):

The html5 document should begin with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Without this line did not work the viewport AppBrowser in Phonegap Android

Comment: The poster's example begins with `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`, and HTML is not case sensitive.

Comment: look at the website according to w3c standards ... http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/Doctypes_and_markup_styles

Comment: Quoting directly from the W3 link you provided: "Elements and attributes are case insensitive, eg <h1> is the same thing as <H1>."