# Zoom in android app with phonegap build

Tags: jquery, android, mobile, cordova

I'm using jQuery Mobile and Phonegap build to make an Android app, and I'd like the user to be able to zoom in and out on the pages to view images in more detail. I've tried searching this issue but none of the answers given worked for me so I'd really appreciate any help. This is what I have in the head of the page:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Is there any way I can change this for the user to be able to zoom in and out?

Answer (score 0):

By default, zooming is disabled because the following meta tag is injected dynamically by jQuery Mobile into your document:

The actual @content value written out for this meta tag is controlled by the $.mobile.metaViewportContent property. It's default value is:

```
    metaViewportContent: "width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"
```

If you want to restore zoom capability you'll have to override the scale values specified so that maximum-scale is greater than the minimum or remove the scale properties from the metaViewportContent to get the default behavior.

To set the property, you'll have to bind to the mobileinit event so you can set the property to your liking. Something like:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
      $.mobile.metaViewportContent = "width=device-width, minimum-scale=1,
       maximum-scale=2";
});
```

Or to remove the scale values:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
      $.mobile.metaViewportContent = "width=device-width";
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Sorry to be dense, but where exactly do I put your code? I'm completely new at this.

Comment: Not worked for me. I tried suggested code but no zoom at all. But thanks for try

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to enable zooming on Android with PhoneGap Build - see my answer on [Enabling viewport pinch-zoom in Phonegap Android application has no effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965396/enbaling-viewport-pinch-zoom-in-phonegap-android-application-has-no-effect) for how to do it in destop PhoneGap.