# How to change PhoneGap's screen size?

Tags: android, mobile, cordova

I'm building an application with PhoneGap. i'm using my Galaxy S2 to test the application, and his screen resolution is 480x800. But when the View is created, his size is 320x800!

I tried too many things, but nothing works...
Is there here anyone that can please help me?

Oh, I'm using android's environment, with Eclipse, ADT, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a way to do that. I already had tried by using a meta viewport, but I guess I don't put everything that is necessary.

Just put this meta tag below and everything should be fine.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />
```