# Cannot get ChildBrowser working on Cordova 2.0.0: Cannot read property 'childBrowser' of undefined

Tags: cordova, cordova-2.0.0, childbrowser

I'm done extensive search online and followed tutorials but I still got Cannot read property 'childBrowser' of undefined.

Here are my steps:

1. download childbrowser.js and included after cordova-2.0.0.js in index.html
2. download ChildBroswer.java and put it in com.phonegap.plugins.childBrowser. I checked the build path and src/ is included.
3. modify the config.xml file by adding the following line (previous examples said plugins.xml which I assume is the old version of config.xml

   plugin name="ChildBrowser" value="com.phonegap.plugins.childBrowser.ChildBrowser"/>
4. add the following into androidmanifest.xml:

   activity android:name="com.phonegap.DroidGap" android:label="@string/app_name">
           intent-filter>
           /intent-filter>
      /activity>
5. My index.html looks like the example here: http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2011/09/phonegap-android-childbrowser-revamp.html
   .

I've run out of ideas why this is happening to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. My childbrowser.js was partially downloaded which causes this error

Answer (score 1):

i have tried it aswell and it never seems to work, you can just change 
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html"); 
to a web link

this page shows you how to add zoom in and out [zoom in phonegap for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668344/zoom-in-phonegap-for-android)

Answer (score 1):

Had this problem too. Realized that the iOS file is named ChildBrowser.js but the Android file is childbrowser.js. Doh!