# Enable Zoom Option In WebView Android

Tags: android, cordova, webview

I am developing the application using PhoneGap. I cannot enable built in zoom in/out in the webview.

I used Following code in onCreate Function

```
WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
web.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

But it did not work.

And The Activity class is

**activity_main.xml**

```
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/webview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Check if you don't have a **ScrollView** wrapping your Webview.

It seems ScrollView gets in the way of the pinch gesture.

To fix it, just take your Webview outside the ScrollView nd then use the same line:

```
webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
```

Comment: my activity_main.xml is having only webView. The above code is the entire activity_main.xml

Comment: Then this line should wrk webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

Comment: am getting web page with scrolling in horizontal and vertical. using above line still not enable zoom

Comment: the zooming is now working. When i changed the webview to CordovaWebView the zooming is working.

Comment: If any issue, you can [ask here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13436/smart-developers-lab)

Comment: Worked for me. Also a tip for those who want the pinch zoom but without the zoom icons displayed:

webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);

Answer (score 6):

### For Cordova 5

This has changed slightly for Cordova 5.1 (I think it changed with 5.0 actually).
**To enable Android zooming for Cordova 5**, add these lines :

> ```
> import android.webkit.WebView;
> import android.webkit.WebSettings; 
> import android.webkit.WebSettings.ZoomDensity;
> ```

and these

> ```
>         WebView webView = (WebView) appView.getEngine().getView();
>         WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
>         settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
>         settings.setSupportZoom(true);
> ```

---

A full sample of your **`src/com/YOURPACKAGE.java`** file:

```
package com.YOURPACKAGE;

import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebSettings; 
import android.webkit.WebSettings.ZoomDensity;


public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        loadUrl(launchUrl);

        WebView webView = (WebView) appView.getEngine().getView();
        WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
        settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        settings.setSupportZoom(true);
        //settings.setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.FAR);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use ==>>**

```
web.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

**before the line  ==>>**

```
web.loadDataWithBaseURL("Your Required params");
```