# No pinch zoom on Jquery mobile Android Phonegap Build app

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, jquery-mobile, zooming

I have difficult in getting pinch zoom to work on Android at the webapp I am creating with Phonegap Build. I need to zoom the entire page, not just a picture. I´m using on HTML the tag `<meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,user-scalable=yes">`

The tag `<preference name='EnableViewportScale' value='true'/>` at config.xml works fine on iOS, I get pinch zoom in app compiled by Phonegap Build service, but not on Android.

I'm using Jquery Mobile v1.4.5 framework and just javascript code, Java/Eclipse is not an option for me. Compiling the app with Cordova and deploy straight to the Android device also gets no zoom.

Is there any JQM or Phonegap Build issue? Or is an Android issue?

Comment: This has been already asked at least four times: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7121053/813951, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668344/zoom-in-phonegap-for-android, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20068390/enable-zoom-option-in-webview-android, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965396/enabling-viewport-pinch-zoom-in-phonegap-android-application-has-no-effect

Answer (score 0):

Try using [panzoom](https://github.com/timmywil/jquery.panzoom)

It allows you to zoom in/out a div.